# How to work with websocket timeout at ctx

Tags: go, websocket, timeout

I have a handler that is upgrades protocol to WS. During the WS interaction, db queries occurs. But ctx timeout fixed for 60 seconds, so after that duration sending requests becomes impossible with this ctx. What's the best practice to work with WS interactions? Creating new ctx with the same fields (except deadline) or setting other timeout middleware for only one http query looks like a crutches.

Comment: In your websocket code, create contexts as needed with a timeout appropriate for the scenario.

Comment: @MuffinTop there are other objects (e.g. user, logger, etc) exists in context that necessary for called funcs, so to do this i need to copy almost all content of context. It doesn't look as best idea.

Comment: Some options: 1) don't set timeout for webocket requests 2) don't set timeouts in middleware. Each handler sets context timeout as appropriate. 3) In websocket handler use a context that only delegats `Value` to the context set by the middleware.